# не подключается библиотека onClickListener

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! спасибо за ответы, кароче запарился не подключается библиотека onClickListener ну в общем есть два активити с уроков скопировал коды и пытался соеденить все вместе получилось каша? потом посидел немного и всё норм красным ниче не светится кроме того самого (this) как я понел изза того что не подключается библиотека onClickListener, чтоб не запутаться и выйтти из данной ситуаций прощу вашей помощи.

```
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    ListView lvMain;
    String[] names;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate() {
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        lvMain.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.names,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);

        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnChecked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChecked);
        btnChecked.setOnClickListener(this);


        names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "checked: ");
        SparseBooleanArray sbArray = lvMain.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 0; i < sbArray.size(); i++) {
            int key = sbArray.keyAt(i);
            if (sbArray.get(key))
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, names[key]);
        }
    }
```

// код сверху мне нужно было прописать так чтобы он отображался в новом созданном активити.  далее мое активити к которому нужно вставить метод который выше и не могу потому что после того как вставлю (this) в моем методе горит красным а библиотека onClickListener не подключается.Мой блок "Меню-2"

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {



/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 4:
                return "Меню-2";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Если вы хотите этим заниматься, прочитайте сначала хорошую книгу по разработке, [вроде этой](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=48070940). Нельзя просто так "копировать коды" и думать, что ты уже программист. То, что вы тут накопипастили - адский трешак, исправлять который и объяснять что не так несколько бессмысленно - это все нужно просто выкинуть. PS: `OnClickListener` не библиотека, а интерфейс обратного вызова (колбэк).

Answer (score 4):

Я так подозреваю что ты данное активи не имплементируешь от View.OnClickListener

В своей активности пропиши:

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {...
```